# Mystery element pushing extra width on mobile

Tags: html, css

I am adding some styling to the following website http://privatepatientmagnet.com/treatments/ and there is an element on the page pushing the width out the side of the viewport.

Have looked in the web inspector and cant find the cause, how would I identify the element causing this?

Comment: Sorry, would you be able to more specifically define the problem, or provide a screenshot highlighting it? Admittedly, I'm not completely sure what you mean.

Comment: Please take a look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry guys, yes I should have been more specific, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's element with `class=".vc_custom_1430292196306"`, in styles (index, line 116 in generated HTML) it has `padding-left: 385px !important`.

Comment: Thanks for this, reason I couldn't find it was that there is not even any content within that div, so no idea what it's purpose is.